# How to pass parameter from page1.aspx to page2.aspx via the session?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, parameters

I have two aspx pages. I need to send a textbox(record_id) value as a parameter from page1.aspx to page2.aspx to be utilized within a SqlCommand query in the VB code behind page.  I would like to pass this parameter using the session.  Page1 is a gridview which displays records from a sql datasource and on the edit button click the user is redirected to page2 which populates several textboxes and drop down lists and allows the user to edit the record. 
page1.aspx:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Page1</h1>
</div>
<%-- <form id="form1" runat="server" style="text-align:left" > --%>
<div id="GridViewContainer" class="GridViewContainer" 
            style="width:4500px;height:700px;" >
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridView"  
    DataKeyNames="record_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15">
    <PagerStyle   
            Font-Bold="true"     
            BackColor="#D6E7FF"  
            ForeColor="Blue"
             /> 
    <%-- <HeaderStyle CssClass="FrozenHeader" /> --%>
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" OnClientClick="InquiryUpdate.aspx">
             <ControlStyle ForeColor="blue" />
        </asp:CommandField> --%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">  
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button   
                        ID="ButtonEdit"  
                        runat="server"  
                        Text="Edit"
                        onclick="ButtonEdit"
                        PostBackUrl="Page2.aspx"
                        CommandName="edit"
                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("record_id") %>'                           
                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit this record?')"  
                        Height="20"  
                        ForeColor="Navy"  
                        Font-Bold="true"  
                        />  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="record_id" HeaderText="Record Id" itemstyle-width="20px"
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="record_id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="Location" itemstyle-width="150px"
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ref_date" HeaderText="Referral Date" itemstyle-width="40px"
            SortExpression="ref_date" ReadOnly="True" />
        <%-- <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="ref_date" HeaderText="Referral Date">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList11" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource12"
                    DataTextField="ref_date" DataValueField="ref_date" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ref_date") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ref_date") %>' 
                  ID="Label2"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> --%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pot_res" HeaderText="Potential Resident" itemstyle-width="200px"
            SortExpression="pot_res" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="app_admit" HeaderText="Approval for Admit" itemstyle-width="50px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"
                    DataTextField="app_admit" DataValueField="app_admit" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("app_admit") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("app_admit") %>' 
                  ID="Label3"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="reason_not_admit" HeaderText="Reason Not Admitting" itemstyle-width="200px"
            SortExpression="reason_not_admit" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="app_by" HeaderText="Denial Approved By" itemstyle-width="200px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList40" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource40"
                    DataTextField="app_by" DataValueField="app_by" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("app_by") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("app_by") %>' 
                  ID="Label40"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="zip_code" HeaderText="Zip Code" itemstyle-width="30px"
            SortExpression="zip_code" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="assess" HeaderText="Assess" itemstyle-width="70px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6"
                    DataTextField="assess" DataValueField="assess" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("assess") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("assess") %>' 
                  ID="Label4"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="tour" HeaderText="Tour" itemstyle-width="50px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7"
                    DataTextField="tour" DataValueField="tour" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("tour") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tour") %>' 
                  ID="Label5"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="hear_us" HeaderText="How did your hear about us?" 
            SortExpression="hear_us" itemstyle-width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name_case_mngr" HeaderText="Name/Case Manager" itemstyle-width="100px"
            SortExpression="name_case_mngr" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="hos_org" HeaderText="Hospital/Organization" itemstyle-width="150px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8"
                    DataTextField="hos_org" DataValueField="hos_org" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("hos_org") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hos_org") %>' 
                  ID="Label6"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="doctor" HeaderText="Doctor" itemstyle-width="150px"
            SortExpression="doctor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pat_diag" HeaderText="Patient Diagnosis" itemstyle-width="150px"
            SortExpression="pat_diag" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="payor_key" HeaderText="Payor(key)" itemstyle-width="50px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource9"
                    DataTextField="payor_key" DataValueField="payor_key" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("payor_key") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payor_key") %>' 
                  ID="Label7"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="payor_detail" HeaderText="Payor Detail" itemstyle-width="150px"
            SortExpression="payor_detail" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="product_key" HeaderText="Product(Key)" itemstyle-width="150px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
                    DataTextField="product_key" DataValueField="product_key" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("product_key") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("product_key") %>' 
                  ID="Label8"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="decision_key" HeaderText="Decision(Key)" itemstyle-width="150px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10"
                    DataTextField="decision_key" DataValueField="decision_key" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("decision_key") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("decision_key") %>' 
                  ID="Label9"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="reason_key" HeaderText="reason(Key)" itemstyle-width="150px">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource11"
                    DataTextField="reason_key" DataValueField="reason_key" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("reason_key") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reason_key") %>' 
                  ID="Label10"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="last_FU_date" HeaderText="Last F/U Date" itemstyle-width="40px"
            SortExpression="last_FU_date" />
        <%-- <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="last_FU_date" HeaderText="Last F/U Date">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList12" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource13"
                    DataTextField="last_FU_date" DataValueField="last_FU_date" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("last_FU_date") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("last_FU_date") %>' 
                  ID="Label11"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> --%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pri_contact" HeaderText="Primary Contact" itemstyle-width="150px"
            SortExpression="pri_contact" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="relationship" HeaderText="Relationship to Resident" itemstyle-width="150px"
            SortExpression="relationship" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="street" HeaderText="Street" itemstyle-width="150px"
            SortExpression="street" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="city" itemstyle-width="100px"/>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="state" HeaderText="State">
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" Runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4"
                    DataTextField="state" DataValueField="state" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("state") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>        
           </EditItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("state") %>' 
                  ID="Label12"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="zip" HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="zip" itemstyle-width="40px"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="phone" itemstyle-width="110px"/>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="comments" 
            HeaderText="Comments" 
            SortExpression="comments" 
            itemstyle-width="250px"/>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="edited_date" HeaderText="Date Edited" itemstyle-width="100px"
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="edited_date" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" >
            <ControlStyle ForeColor="blue" />
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#d6e7ff" ForeColor="black" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

and page2.aspx.vb:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Public Class InquiryUpdate
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If HttpContext.Current.User IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.SqlDataSource6.SelectParameters.Clear()
                Me.SqlDataSource6.SelectParameters.Add("UserName", System.Data.DbType.[String], HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
            End If
        End If

        Dim dv As Data.DataView = DirectCast(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), Data.DataView)
        Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("InquiryConnectionString").ToString()
        Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(conString)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT record_id, location, CONVERT(nvarchar(30),ref_date,110) as ref_date, pot_res, app_admit, reason_not_admit, app_by, zip_code, assess, tour, hear_us, name_case_mngr, hos_org, doctor, pat_diag, payor_key, payor_detail, product_key, decision_key, reason_key, CONVERT(nvarchar(30),last_FU_date,110) as last_FU_date, pri_contact, relationship, street,city, state, zip, phone, comments FROM temp_inquiry_table_denial where record_id='520'", sqlConn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@record_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DirectCast(Session("record_id"), Integer)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            DisplayControls(True)
            txtLocation.Text = dt.Rows(0)("location").ToString()
            txtRefDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ref_date").ToString()
            pot_res.Text = dt.Rows(0)("pot_res").ToString()
            txtAppAdmit.Text = dt.Rows(0)("app_admit").ToString()
            txtReasonNotAdmitting.Text = dt.Rows(0)("reason_not_admit").ToString()
            txtAppBy.Text = dt.Rows(0)("app_by").ToString()
            txtZipCode.Text = dt.Rows(0)("zip_code").ToString()
            txtAssess.Text = dt.Rows(0)("assess").ToString()
            txtTour.Text = dt.Rows(0)("tour").ToString()
            txtHearUs.Text = dt.Rows(0)("hear_us").ToString()
            txtNameCaseMngr.Text = dt.Rows(0)("name_case_mngr").ToString()
            txtHosOrg.Text = dt.Rows(0)("hos_org").ToString()
            txtDoctor.Text = dt.Rows(0)("doctor").ToString()
            txtPatDiag.Text = dt.Rows(0)("pat_diag").ToString()
            txtPayorKey.Text = dt.Rows(0)("payor_key").ToString()
            txtPayorDetail.Text = dt.Rows(0)("payor_detail").ToString()
            txtProductKey.Text = dt.Rows(0)("product_key").ToString()
            txtDecisionKey.Text = dt.Rows(0)("decision_key").ToString()
            txtReasonKey.Text = dt.Rows(0)("reason_key").ToString()
            txtFUdate.Text = dt.Rows(0)("last_FU_date").ToString()
            txtPContact.Text = dt.Rows(0)("pri_contact").ToString()
            txtRelationship.Text = dt.Rows(0)("relationship").ToString()
            txtStreet.Text = dt.Rows(0)("street").ToString()
            txtCity.Text = dt.Rows(0)("city").ToString()
            txtState.Text = dt.Rows(0)("state").ToString()
            txtZip2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("zip").ToString()
            txtPhone.Text = dt.Rows(0)("phone").ToString()
            txtComments.Text = dt.Rows(0)("comments").ToString()
        Else
            DisplayControls(False)
        End If
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub DisplayControls(ByVal visibility As Boolean)
        txtLocation.Visible = visibility
        txtRefDate.Visible = visibility
        pot_res.Visible = visibility
        txtAppAdmit.Visible = visibility
        txtReasonNotAdmitting.Visible = visibility
        txtAppBy.Visible = visibility
        txtZipCode.Visible = visibility
        txtAssess.Visible = visibility
        txtTour.Visible = visibility
        txtHearUs.Visible = visibility
        txtNameCaseMngr.Visible = visibility
        txtHosOrg.Visible = visibility
        txtDoctor.Visible = visibility
        txtPatDiag.Visible = visibility
        txtPayorKey.Visible = visibility
        txtPayorDetail.Visible = visibility
        txtProductKey.Visible = visibility
        txtDecisionKey.Visible = visibility
        txtReasonKey.Visible = visibility
        txtFUdate.Visible = visibility
        txtPContact.Visible = visibility
        txtRelationship.Visible = visibility
        txtStreet.Visible = visibility
        txtCity.Visible = visibility
        txtState.Visible = visibility
        txtZip2.Visible = visibility
        txtPhone.Visible = visibility
        txtComments.Visible = visibility
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: could you boil down your problem to a smaller code example and formulate a question around the problem?

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. Your problem statement seems to be your answer.

Comment: I need to pass the record_id textbox value from the gridview upon selection to the page2.aspx.vb page to be used in the query that populated the update form.  I am having difficulty passing this parameter from page1 to page2 via the session.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do:

In the gridview [rowcommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event. Get the record_id using the command argument (which you have already setup).

Set the session with this record_id

Finally do Response.Redirect or Session.Transfer to Page2.aspx

HTH

Comment: Im having difficulty with the syntax for setting the session with the record_id. Could you supply sample code?

Comment: simple Session("record_id") = <value> :-)....<value> should be your command argument. HTH

Comment: Session("record_id") = CType(row.FindControl("record_id"), Label)Response.Redirect("InquiryUpdate.aspx")

Comment: You are assigning the label to session. Try this: Session("record_id") = CType(row.FindControl("record_id"), Label).text

Comment: This gives me this error: The parameterized query '(@record_id int)SELECT record_id, location, CONVERT(nvarchar(30)' expects the parameter '@record_id', which was not supplied

Comment: Does may a difference that I am setting this session in: Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in GridView Rowcommand and see if you get the correct record_id from command argument....the error you get is because you are not setting the parameter record_id to the stored procedure

Comment: Also I am assuming that the query which you have written in the code block is just a sample with hardcoded record_id (520)